# c# static constructor not called from derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance, static-constructor

```
class Bus<T>
{
    static Bus()
    {
        foreach(FieldInfo fi in typeof(T).GetFields())
        {
            if(fi.FieldType == typeof(Argument))
            {
                fi.SetValue(typeof(T), new Argument("busyname", "busyvalue"));
            }
        }
    }
}
class Buss : Bus<Buss>
{
    public static Argument field;
}
```

Any ideas how to make this work so that a reference to the static field in Buss triggers the static constructor in Bus?

Comment: why static contructors? A static constructor is used to initialize any static data, or to perform a particular action that needs to be performed once only.

Comment: 'field' _is_ static data and only needs to be initialized once, hence static constructors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that this matters to you probably means that you are using static constructors wrong.

With that in mind, you could make a static constructor in `Buss` that manually invokes the static constructor in `Bus`.  Note that it's not possible to run a static constructor more than once.

Comment: static constructor cannot be called directly.

Comment: I realize by 'wrong' that you probably mean my OOP is off.  However, I feel that to be able to inherit static members (including static constructors) would actually be more object-oriented.

Comment: @adt: Just refer to any static field or method, and it will be called implicitly.

Comment: can you directly call static contructor?

Comment: @adt: Not explicitly, but calling it can be accomplished, like I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

The static constructor of a generic type is invoked exactly once per `Type`, when that type is referenced.

Calling `Buss x = new Buss()` will invoke the static constructor of `Bus<Buss>`.

Calling `Bus<Buss> x = new Bus<Buss>()` will also invoke the static constructor of `Bus<Buss>`, but it will do so for it's type argument `Buss`, setting `Buss.field`.

If you create a `class Bugs : Bus<Buss>` it will never set `Bugs.field`, as it will first resolve the type argument `Buss`, which invokes the static constructor of it's base class `Bus<Buss>`, setting `Buss.field`. When it tries to call the static constructor of `Bugs` base class, it will think it had already invoked the static `Bus<Buss>` constructor and skip it.

Basically if I copy paste your code, create a dummy `Argument` class and create a new instance of `Buss`, the static constructor *is* invoked and `Buss.field` *is* set to an instance of `Argument`, but I do recognize some strange behavoir here in which I'd have to advise not to use reflection from a static method to reach subclasses' statics.

The example you provided only works because `Buss` is the type argument for itself.

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645612%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) that 'Static constructors are not inherited'. I guess this is similar to static fields which are not inherited either.

Comment: "static fields which are not inherited": I have in my code (boiled down) `class T1{ public static string s1="s1"; } class T2: T1 { void f(){ Console.WriteLine(s1); }}`. Does that not count as inheritance? One could legitimately expect that the static constructor of a base class is executed before the static constructor of one of its subcclasses is executed, since it may perform static initializations needed by the derived class as well.