# Why aren't all static constructors called in C# (i.e. those of the parent classes)?

Tags: c#, static-constructor

I have three classes, `Base`, `Derived` and `Final`. `Derived` derives from `Base` and `Final` derives from `Derived`. All three classes have a static constructor. Class `Derived` as a public static method called `Setup`. When I call `Final.Setup`, I expect that all three static constructors get executed, but only the one in `Derived` gets run.

Here is the sample source code:

```
    abstract class Base
    {
        static Base()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine ("Base");
        }
    }

    abstract class Derived : Base
    {
        static Derived()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine ("Derived");
        }

        public static void Setup()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine ("Setup");
        }
    }

    sealed class Final : Derived
    {
        static Final()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine ("Final");
        }
    }
```

This makes only partially sense to me. I understand that calling `Final.Setup()` is in fact just an alias for `Derived.Setup()`, so skipping the static constructor in `Final` seems fair enough. However, why isn't the static constructor of `Base` called?

I can fix this by calling into a no-operation static method of `Base` or by accessing some dummy static method of `Base`. But I was wondering: what is the reasoning behind this apparently strange behavior?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Related, not a dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390960/c-static-constructor-not-called-from-derived-class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A static constructor is called when (according to [TCPL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321741765)):

- An instance of the class type is created.
- Any of the static members of the class type are referenced.

As an example, consider a class with the static `Main` method in which execution begins: if you have a static constructor, it will be called *before* the Main method is called.

Note that even before a static constructor is executed, any static fields are initialized to their default value and then the static field initializers are executed for those field. Only then, the static constructor (cctor) is executed.

---

To answer your question more directly: static constructors are not inherited, and they cannot be called directly, hence your `Base` cctor will not be called in your scenario, unless you give the abstract `Base` class a static method and call that first, i.e. as in `Base.Initialize()`, as you already suggested.

About the reasoning, that's simple, thinking C# (in Java this is different): static methods are not inherited, thus static constructors should neither be inherited as this could cause unwanted side effects (a cctor called when nothing references that class).

Comment: Thank you for your clarifications. This makes now sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Static methods belong to the class and there is no inheritance. The fact that you can call `Final.Setup` is just a syntactic sugar for calling Derived.Setup, so no static member of Final has been referenced - therefore the static constructor is not called.
Same for Base class - there is no inheritance on static members, so the Base class is not involved in any way here.

Answer (score 0):

The C# rules dictate that static constructors are called before the first instance of the  class is created or any static member is touched, ergo, possibly never, as in your case.

Comment: @phresnel: in my case, I never create any object, just calling `Derived.Setup()` causes the static constructor to run on `Derived`. So no, the static constructors are not only called before an instance of a class is being created.

Comment: @phresnel Not exactly: "A static constructor is called automatically to initialize the class before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced." from the link in the comment. This means if he accesses anything in Base its static constructor will fire.

Comment: @Pierre I guess my comment answers your question. You never does anything with Base, so by the above rule, its static constructor will not fire.

Comment: @lasseespeholt: You are right, that was also my conclusion. However, in my mind, accessing some static variables in a derived class was equivalent to an implicit reference to the base class... I still find this a little odd.

Comment: @Pierre I tend to agree with you :) However, if you really need this, you properly have to refactor your code :/

Comment: @Pierre: Exactly, because you never create an object are refer to any member, it won't be called