# Why the order of entering static .ctors is different from instance .ctors in inherited classes?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, constructor, static-constructor

Why `var b = new B()` firstly enters **`static B()`** .ctor and than **`static A()`** `.ctor` and not vice versa like the instance constructors does (**`public A()`** and than **`public B()`**)?

```
public class A
{
    static A() {}
    public A() {}
}

public class B : A
{
    static B() {}
    public B() {}
}
```

Comment: This is basically the same as [Why aren't all static constructors called in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503588/why-arent-all-static-constructors-called-in-c-sharp-i-e-those-of-the-parent-c), and the answer is basically the same: Static constructors are not inherited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically the instance constructor of `B` is entered first. But the first thing it does is calling the constructor of `A` and only then goes to the user defined body.

So I assume that directly before the constructor of `B` is entered the static constructor of `B` needs to run.

Then the constructor of `B` calls the constructor of `A`, which triggers the static constructor of `A`.

Comment: The rules for static constructors are spelled out in the language specification. Specifically, static constructors run when "an instance of the class type is created [or] any of the static members of the class type are referenced." Note that "a static member of a derived type is referenced" is not on the list.